# How to login to website using python for scraping purpose?

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, http-post

I have a login page that I need to pass before downloading the excel file.

When i check using inspect element, I get the following elements:

```html
<input name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$SubContent$SubContent$passwordTextBox" type="password" id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_SubContent_SubContent_passwordTextBox" style="width:150px;">

<input name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$SubContent$SubContent$userNameTextBox" type="text" id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_SubContent_SubContent_userNameTextBox" style="width:150px;">
```

[image]

```py
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re
import pandas as pd
import requests
import urllib

url = 'https://www.canfax.ca/Report/SpreadsheetReport.aspx?catalogue=FullSpreadsheets&group=Weekly+Fed+Steer&report=Alberta'
payload = {'ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$SubContent$SubContent$userNameTextBox': 'username', 'ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$SubContent$SubContent$passwordTextBox': 'password'}

p=requests.post(url, data=payload)

print(p.text)
```

I am getting the html login text as output. I have used the input name tag as payload.Please see the pictures below for reference

I have added the cookies:

[image]

Comment: it may need to send all values which browser send to server - and page may send other (hidden) values. It may also need to use `Session` to `GET` cookies and later `POST` them with other values.

Comment: @furas I did try a method to dynamically get it but was unable to do so. This is the link: https://www.canfax.ca/Main.aspx

Comment: when you use `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab: `Network`) then you can see what it sends to server. There are also values like `__EVENTTARGET`, `__VIEWSTATE`, etc. and server may need it to compare with data in its database. it also send cookies `ASP.NET_SessionId` and if you don't send it then server treats you as new user which has to login again. And later you have to send cookies again and again to server and it checks this cookie in its database to confirm that you are logged in.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71795037/need-help-in-getting-into-website-after-log-in-using-beautiful-soup @furas, I tried this and it didn't work

Comment: I can't test it but your code has to behave like human using web browser - first you may have to GET `Main.aspx` and POST to the same `Main.aspx`, and later load your page. And when I first try to load your page then browser redirects me to `Login.aspx` and it sends POST to the same `Login.aspx`. But you try to send POST to `SpreadsheetReport.aspx` and this can be mistake.

Comment: thanks @furas. I have added the cookies in the description. So, how would i send the cookies? I did not get that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243717/discussion-between-shruthi-ravishankar-and-furas).

Comment: first you have to send password to correct URL - as for me you send it to wrong URL so it doesn't know what to do with this password.

Comment: oh, I corrected the url. now I am in the website. If I now access the spreadsheet url, will it work?

Comment: I have no idea - I don't have account to test this page. But I assume that if you logged in (and you use Session to keep cookies) then it should give you file.

Comment: I haven't used session to keep cookies? I wanted help on that.

Comment: `s = requests.Session()` and later use `s.get()` and `s.post()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71795037/need-help-in-getting-into-website-after-log-in-using-beautiful-soup, the code is in here. I posted the code here and I have used requests.Session(),r = s.get(link) and res = s.post(link,data=payload). Sorry, I am new to this. I haven't added the ASP.NET_SessionId part to the payload.

Comment: @furas I somehow managed to get into the link but now when I try to read it using url1 = 'https://www.canfax.ca/Report/SpreadsheetReport.aspx?catalogue=FullSpreadsheets&group=Weekly+Fed+Steer&report=Alberta'
    t=s.get(url1), I get weird symbols when i print(t.text).

Comment: If you get excel `.xlsx` then you can see strange chars because it is NOT text file and you have to use special modules to uncompress/parse .xlsx (ie. `pandas.read_excel()`). Maybe first save it in file in `bytes mode` - `f = open(..., 'wb')` - using `t.content` instead of `t.text` - `f.write(t.content)` - and later open it in Excel to see if it can open it.

Comment: Well, it's not .xlsx. this is the link: https://www.canfax.ca/Report/SpreadsheetReport.aspx?catalogue=FullSpreadsheets&group=Weekly+Fed+Steer&report=Alberta.

Comment: https://www.canfax.ca/Report/SpreadsheetReport.aspx?catalogue=FullSpreadsheets&group=Weekly+Fed+Steer&report=Alberta

Comment: I cannot seem to put the entire link in the comment, but it is in the description above. the url field which is a spreadsheet

Comment: this link can send you excel data and you can't display it because excel doesn't keep data as plain text - it keeps data as `xml` compressed in `zip` - and you have to save data in file and use `Excel` to see data (or use functions like `pandas.read_excel` to display in console)

Comment: Yes, but it isn't an excel link,  this is the last part of the link aspx?catalogue=FullSpreadsheets&group=Weekly+Fed+Steer&report=Alberta

Comment: There is no .xls extension

Comment: @furas Could we get on a zoom or google meet call so that you can take a look at my program? That would be really helpful. Thank you

Comment: @furas I have detailed out the question for this with the code and everything here if you aren't comfortable with a call: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71807818/python-getting-weird-symbols-when-i-use-get-request. Thank you

Comment: @furas I figured it out. Thank you for your help throughout