# Python: Getting weird symbols when I use get request?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape spreadsheets after logging into a asps.net website.

the process flow is: Login to the webpage, then click on the spreadsheet link and get the excel data

The login link is : https://www.canfax.ca/Main.aspx.
I figured out a way to login using requests and beautiful soup. But now when I try to download the spreadsheet, I am getting weird symbols.

```
link = 'https://www.canfax.ca/Main.aspx'

payload = {
    'ctl00$MainContent$userNameTextBox':'username',
    'ctl00$MainContent$passwordTextBox': 'password',
    'ctl00$MainContent$signInButton': 'Sign In'



page = 1


with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36'
#     s.headers["Accept-Encoding"]:" deflate;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"
    s.headers["Accept-Language"]: "en-GB,en-US"
    s.headers["Content-Type"]:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    s.headers["Referer"]: "https://www.canfax.ca/Main.aspx"
    s.headers["Sec-Fetch-Dest"]: "document"
    s.headers["sec-ch-ua"]: '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="100", "Google Chrome";v="100"'
    s.headers["sec-ch-ua-platform"]: '"macOS"'
    s.headers["Sec-Fetch-Mode"]: "navigate"
    s.headers["Sec-Fetch-Site"]: 'same-origin'
    s.headers["Sec-Fetch-User"]: '?1'
        
    s.headers["Cookie"]: "AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1; ASP.NET_SessionId=iekqccbp4lzkjuiqujpweifk; __utmc=219132171; __utmz=219132171.1649363793.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utma=219132171.167833154.1649363793.1649432375.1649498873.5; __utmt=1; __utmb=219132171.3.10.1649498873"
        
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    payload['__VIEWSTATE'] = soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATE")['value']
    payload['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'] = soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")['value']
    payload['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = soup.select_one("#__EVENTVALIDATION")['value']


    res = s.post(link,data=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)
    
    s.headers["Content-Type"]= "application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8" # this is to change the previous content type.
    url1 = 'https://www.canfax.ca/Report/SpreadsheetReport.aspx?catalogue=FullSpreadsheets&group=Weekly+Fed+Steer&report=Alberta'
    t=s.get(url1)
```

my output that i get is :

```
�"$"#,##0�\$#,##0�0.0Calibri1���Calibri1���Calibri1���Calibri"$"#,##0;\-"$"#,##0"$"#,##0;[Red]\-"$"#,##0"$"#,##0.00;\-"$"#,##0.00#"$"#,##0.00;[Red]\-"$"#,##0.005*0_-"$"* #,##0_-;\-"$"* #,##0_-;_-"$"* "-"_-;_-@_-,)'_-* #,##0_-;\-* #,##0_-;_-* "-"_-;_-@_-=,8_-"$"* #,##0.00_-;\-"$"* #,##0.00_-;_-"$"* "-"??_-;_-@_-4+/_-* #,##0.00_-;\-* #,##0.00_-;_-* "-"??_-;_-@_-�"$"#,##0_);\("$"#,##0\)!�"$"#,##0_);[Red]\("$"#,##0\)"�"$"#,##0.00_);\("$"#,##0.00\)'�""$"#,##0.00_);[Red]\("$"#,##0.00\)7�2_("$"* #,##0_);_("$"* \(#,##0\);_("$"* "-"_);_(@_).�)_(* #,##0_);_(* \(#,##0\);_(* "-"_);_(@_)?�:_("$"* #,##0.00_);_("$"* \(#,##0.00\);_("$"* "-"??_);_(@_)6�1_(* #,##0.00_);_(* \(#,##0.00\);_(* "-"??_);_(@_)4�/_(* #,##0.0_);_(* \(#,##0.0\);_(* "-"??_);_(@_)0�+_(* #,##0_);_(* \(#,##0\);_(* "-"??_);_(@_)
�0.000�"Yes";"Yes";"No"�"True";"True";"False"�"On";"On";"Off"]�,[$� -2]\ #,##0.00_);[Red]\([$� -2]\ #,##0.00\)��� � ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� � � ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� �  �� ���� �
�}�00_)����[$� -�##0.�          ��� ��� �� ��� ���� ��� �`� ��� �� ��� �� ��� ���� �    �� �� ��� �� ��� �a�� ��� �� � � � � � � �"� � H/ �� � � � �#� �#� �    #� �#� K�|L�A
00_)����[$� -???�##0.???�           ???�
00_)(65
??v�00_)�̙�[$� -�##0.�          �
�e�00_)���[$� -x:����00_)�������[�����##    �����   
???�00_)����[???�## ???�   
    ???�
60% - Accent6   23��������%�"Accent1A�Accent1O�������%�#Accent2A!�Accent2�PM�����%�$Accent3A%�Accent3��Y�����%�%Accent4A)�Accent4�d������%�&Accent5A-�Accent5K�������%�'Accent6A1�Accent6   ��F�����%�(Bad9�Bad��������%�)Calculation��Calculation�������}�%������  ���*
Check Cell�
Check Cell���������%�???��???��???� �???��+�� �Comma�,��(�  Comma [0]�-��&Currency�.��.�Currency [0]�/Explanatory TextG5�Explanatory Text��%�0� �F  �Followed Hyperlink���� 1Good;�Good������a�%�2  Heading 1G� Heading 1I}�%O����3 Heading 2G� Heading 2I}�%�?�����4   Heading 3G� Heading 3I}�%23�����5   Heading 49� Heading 4I}�%�6�4�  Hyperlink
���
7Inputu�Input��̙��??v�%������   ���8Linked CellK�Linked Cell��}�%�����9NeutralA�Neutral������e�%���"�Normal�    :Noteb
�Note��������������������   ������;Outputw�Output������???�%�???��???��???� �???��<��$�Percent�
=Title1�TitleI}�%�
>TotalM�Total�%O���O����?Warning Text?�Warning Text���%X�TableStyleMedium9PivotStyleLight16��8�������������������������������3f������ff���f����������������������������������̙����3f�3���������fff����3f3�f333�3�3f33�333\���`�F2Alberta Fed Steer Price����5��OAlberta Weekly Fed Steer PricesSource:  CanFaxWeek  Cdn $/cwt�
�1^B�
d����MbP?_*+��%�����&�?'�?(�?)�?M�\\CFXDC02\Lexmark MS817n����
dXXLetter����GIS4DINU"p��W�pSMTJ`{4104DF81-B4B1-427d-93EA-628FE2120C5A}InputBinUSEPRINTERRESDLLUniresDLLPaperSizeLETTERMediaTypeAUTOResolution600DPIColorModeMonoOrientationPORTRAITCollateONDuplexNONEOutputBinUSEPRINTERJobStapleAllDocumentsUSEPRINTERJobHolePunchUSEPRINTERV4DM�"dXX�?�?&U}�A}A}$   A:w�������  �
��������������������
@�
B�
B�
C�HDp�@Dt�@Dx�@D|�@D��@D��@D��@D��@D��@D��@D��@�NC�?E�u�@E���@E��@Fs�@F�G�@F�%�@AZ�@AQ�@A���@A�l�@A���@�C@E�?�@E ]@E�G�z�`@�$FA��@F�}�@F�O�@A�-�@A�b�   A�G�ztd@�
�@GA7�@F�P�@F�>�@A�@A[�@AA�@Am�@A�N�@�C@E3�@E{�@Eq=
ף�a@�6F��@FAy�@F��@A���@A�6�@A��@A���@A�q�@�*   C@E��@E��@EM�@F�D�@FAN�@    F=
ףp�c@   A���(\gd@   Afffff^c@~
        A�@ 
Ffffff�b@   H�
C@E���@E���@
E�G�zDa@�
G(g@F��@
F=
ףp�c@
Aq=
ףpd@
A��(\��b@~

    A��@

A��(\�c@~

A$�@�6C@E���@E�p�@E�b�@FAz�@GA��@F��@F�@A=
ףp�b@�  A�h�@A��@A���@�0C @E��@E�g�@G��@F���@GY�@F�U�@H~
F��@    J~

C"@E���@E��@G�@F��@F�u�@F��@A�3�@A�U�@A���@ 
A=
ףp�b@~
A��@�C$@E�m�@EO�@E���(\a@~
G`h@G�*F��@A��@A    �@A��@A�H�@A��@�6C&@Ec�@G:�@E��@F�7�@FA�@F\�@A�!�@A��(\�Zc@~
    A��@
A�G�z�b@~
A��@�HC(@E��@E�@E���@FAF�@F�e�@F���@A��@A��@F0b@A�b@
�C*@E�m�@E9�@E�����1b@�*F�q�@FA2�@F�@Fd@A�O�@A��@   
HA�G�zLd@�C,@Ep[@E��@E��(\�*b@�F���@G�d@FA��@A��(\�zc@~
Ai�@    F������b@�
Au�@A���@�0C.@E�\�@E�@E^�@F���@F�X�@F��@A���(\_c@�AF�@A��@A���@
�6C0@E��@E=�@E�r�@FA��@F��@FA�@A���@Afffffd@�   A�I�@Ae�@
�0C1@E���@E��@EHb@F���@FA*�@F�S�@A�G�zTd@�A���@A���@F�c@
�$C2@E�X�@E�]�@E�b@FA��@F�G�zDc@~
F���@A��(\�zd@Ffffff&d@�    A���@F��@
�0C3@E���@E�R�@E�f�@F���@Gd@F���@Aq=
ף�c@�A�v�@F�Z@A���@
�0C4@E��@EV�@E���@F��@F���@F    �@A���(\Gb@�Ax�@A���@   
A��(\�rd@�6C5@E��@EL�@G���@F��@F�D�@FA��@A��@A�G�zlb@~
    A���@
A=
ףpmd@�C6@E�@E��@Ffffff�b@�0F���@Fj�@F�e�@A�@A�}�@A1�@A�@
�$C7@E�g�@E��@F�~�@F���@F�G�z�c@�F���@A���@A=
ףp-b@�  A���@A�@
�<C8@E�@E���@F���@FAy�@F��@F�g�@A��@FW� A=
ףpMa@~

�@�$C9@E�s�@E�W�@F��@F��@Ffffff�a@F������c@�A�G�@A���@A��@A���@
�C:@E*�@GF�G�ztc@~
F��@Gq=
ףb@�Fs�@A���@A���@Ar�@  
Aq=
ף�c@�C;@EZ�@G�G�b�@Fx�@F��(\��b@�F�a@A��@I� A"�@A�^�@
�B�XZR~Rh��hvftzLx�bbb�bnlbx`n� �!�"�#�$�%�&�'�(�)�*�+�,�-�.�/�0�1�2�3�4�5�6�7�8�9�� C<@E���@E0�@ Ffffff^d@� G�@F���@ F=
ףpb@~
 A�4�@ Aq=
b@�     A�$�@A���@
�*!C=@E��@E�9�@F��@F��@FO�@!Fq=
ףb@~
!A���@!FfffffFb@�!  A�@Ac�@
�@FA��@"F�G�ztb@~
"F���@"A��(\��b@�"A���@A.�@ "
Aq=
ף�b@�$#C?@Ew�@E�@G�^�@G�@#F=
ףpmb@�#F���@A��@#A�G�zTb@�# A?�@Ab�@
�$$C@@E��@E�"�@F$�@F��@$F��(\�Zb@�$F���@A��@AHb$    A�Q���`@~
$
A���@�0%C�@@E��@EA�@F��@F��@F���@F���@%A��(\��a@%I% A=
ףpa@~
%
A���@�$&CA@E��@E4�@F�>�@F��@&F�Q��ka@�&F��@A��@&Aq=
ף�a@~
&   A���@&
A�G�zLc@�'C�A@E�l�@E�F�@'F���(\d@�'F��@G�@F��@A��@'A=
ףp�a@~
'   A���@'
Aq=
ף�c@�*(CB@Eg�@E�]@Fpd@F���@F%�@(F��(\��`@�(A���@A�[�@A�@A�c@
�B)C�B@EF�@E?�@F���@G+�@GP�@F&�@A���@A���@A�I�@ )
A�Q���c@�**CC@E�4�@E���@F���@F���@F�/�@*F��(\��`@�*A���@F��@A�*�@A���@
�+C�C@E���@EO�@F���@+F���(\d@+F���(\W`@�+F���@A��@+A�Q��ka@�+   A�,�@A���@
�H,CD@E��@E�@G�d@G�L�@F:�@F���@Au�@At�@A�L�@A��@
�0-C�D@E��@E�3�@F)�@F���@FV�@F��@-A�Q��c@-Afffff�a@�-   A}�@A���@
�0.CE@E��@E��@G�d@G���@F��@F���@.A�Q���b@.A���(\�a@.    A�Q���`@.
A�Q��sc@�$/C�E@E�}�@E��@F���@FA��@/F=
ףp�`@/Fq=
ף�a@~
/A��@/Aq=
ף�a@�/  AH�@F0c@
�60CF@E9�@E'�@GA�@FA��@F�   �@F���@A��@0A�Q���a@0   Ffffff�`@0
H�$1C�F@E�G�@E�W�@F�e@F���@1F��(\�ja@~
1F&�@1Afffff�b@�1A��@F�`@A��@
�<2CG@E�@�@Eo�@G�e@G��@F��@F��@F�@A���2 H2
A�Q���c@�03C�G@E���@EY�@F�(�@F;�@F�Y�@FJ�@3A������b@�3A���@A���@    3
H�*4CH@E�
�@E���@F���@F���@F��@4Ffffff�b@~
4A�t�@4F������b@�4  A���@A�@
�$5C�H@E*�@E��@F��@G6�@5F���(\�b@�5F���@A��@5A�G�zDc@�5 F��@A��@
�6CI@EE�@E��@G��@6F���(\Wc@�6F�@F!�@A/�@AC�6    A=
ףpma@~
6
A�#�@�7C�I@EK�@E��@FA��@7F�Q��#d@~
7F�-�@7F�Q��d@~
7A���@7A�Q���c@�7   A�^�@AA*�@
�$8CJ@F�?�@E``@G���@FA�@8F������c@8G8A�Q��Sd@�8 A���@A.�@
~
9C�J@9H~
��v�xvp��bXb�Ln|�hv\fvxv�l>�@9:A
�7����D
��
����JanetJanet HovisMicrosoft Excel@LS��*�@��`L�K�Gf�����%  �Ji�8'��'����"System
�-����-'�����   �7'�����    �7'�����    �7����- �������-��-@    !���-����-�7����-����-  -$--�   ����-   -$--�   ����-   -$--�   ����-   -$--�   ����-   -$--�   ����-   -$--�   ����-   -$--�   ����-   -$--�   ����-   -$      --� ����-   -$      

    --� ����-   -$


--� ����-   -$--�   ����-   -$--�   ����-   -$--�   ����-   -$--�   ����-   -$--�   ����-   -$--�   ����-   -$--�   ����-   -$--�   ����-   -$--�   ����-   -$--�   ����-   -$--�   -'��'��--�7-����-   -$)**))--�  ����-   -$)**))--�  ����-   -$)**))--�  ����-   -$)**))--�  ����-   -$)**))--�  ����-   -$)**))--�  ����-   -$)**))--�  ����-   -$)**))--�  ����-   -$)*    *   ))--�   ����-   -$  )   *
*
)   )--�    ����-   -$
)
**)
)--�    ����-   -$)**))--�  ����-   -$)**))--�  ����-   -$)**))--�  ����-   -$)**))--�  ����-   -$)**))--�  ����-   -$)**))--�  ����-   -$)**))--�  ����-   -$)**))--�  ����-   -$)**))--�  ����-   -$)**))--�  ����-   -$)**))--�  -'��'��--�7-����-   -$:;;::--�  ����-   -$:;;::--�  ����-   -$:;;::--�  ����-   -$:;;::--�  ����-   -$:;;::--�  ����-   -$:;;::--�  ����-   -$:;;::--�  ����-   -$:;;::--�  ����-   -$:;    ;   ::--�   ����-   -$  :   ;
;
:   :--�    ����-   -$
:
;;:
:--�    ����-   -$:;;::--�  ����-   -$:;;::--�  ����-   -$:;;::--�  ����-   -$:;;::--�  ����-   -$:;;::--�  ����-   -$:;;::--�  ����-   -$:;;::--�  ����-   -$:;;::--�  ����-   -$:;;::--�  ����-   -$:;;::--�  ����-   -$:;;::--�  -'��'��--�7-����-   -$KLLKK--�  ����-   -$KLLKK--�  ����-   -$KLLKK--�  ����-   -$KLLKK--�  ����-   -$KLLKK--�  ����-   -$KLLKK--�  ����-   -$KLLKK--�  ����-   -$KLLKK--�  ����-   -$KL    L   KK--�   ����-   -$  K   L
L
K   K--�    ����-   -$
K
LLK
K--�    ����-   -$KLLKK--�  ����-   -$KLLKK--�  ����-   -$KLLKK--�  ����-   -$KLLKK--�  ����-   -$KLLKK--�  ����-   -$KLLKK--�  ����-   -$KLLKK--�  ����-   -$KLLKK--�  ����-   -$KLLKK--�  ����-   -$KLLKK--�  ����-   -$KLLKK--�  -'��'��--�7-����-   -$\]]\\--�  ����-   -$\]]\\--�  ����-   -$\]]\\--�  ����-   -$\]]\\--�  ����-   -$\]]\\--�  ����-   -$\]]\\--�  ����-   -$\]]\\--�  ����-   -$\]]\\--�  ����-   -$\]    ]   \\--�   ����-   -$  \   ]
]
\   \--�    ����-   -$
\
]]\
\--�    ����-   -$\]]\\--�  ����-   -$\]]\\--�  ����-   -$\]]\\--�  ����-   -$\]]\\--�  ����-   -$\]]\\--�  ����-   -$\]]\\--�  ����-   -$\]]\\--�  ����-   -$\]]\\--�  ����-   -$\]]\\--�  ����-   -$\]]\\--�  ����-   -$\]]\\--�  -'��'��--�7-����-   -$mnnmm--�  ����-   -$mnnmm--�  ����-   -$mnnmm--�  ����-   -$mnnmm--�  ����-   -$mnnmm--�  ����-   -$mnnmm--�  ����-   -$mnnmm--�  ����-   -$mnnmm--�  ����-   -$mn    n   mm--�   ����-   -$  m   n
n
m   m--�    ����-   -$
m
nnm
m--�    ����-   -$mnnmm--�  ����-   -$mnnmm--�  ����-   -$mnnmm--�  ����-   -$mnnmm--�  ����-   -$mnnmm--�  ����-   -$mnnmm--�  ����-   -$mnnmm--�  ����-   -$mnnmm--�  ����-   -$mnnmm--�  ����-   -$mnnmm--�  ����-   -$mnnmm--�  -'��'��--�7-����-   -$~~~--�    ����-   -$~~~--�    ����-   -$~~~--�    ����-   -$~~~--�    ����-   -$~~~--�    ����-   -$~~~--�    ����-   -$~~~--�    ����-   -$~~~--�    ����-   -$~     ~~--�   ����-   -$  ~   

~   ~--�    ����-   -$
~
~
~--�    ����-   -$~~~--�    ����-   -$~~~--�    ����-   -$~~~--�    ����-   -$~~~--�    ����-   -$~~~--�    ����-   -$~~~--�    ����-   -$~~~--�    ����-   -$~~~--�    ����-   -$~~~--�    ����-   -$~~~--�    ����-   -$~~~--�    -'��'��--�7-����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$��    �   ��--�   ����-   -$  �   �
�
�   �--�    ����-   -$
�
���
�--�    ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  -'��'��--�7-����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$��    �   ��--�   ����-   -$  �   �
�
�   �--�    ����-   -$
�
���
�--�    ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  -'��'��--�7-����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$��    �   ��--�   ����-   -$  �   �
�
�   �--�    ����-   -$
�
���
�--�    ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  -'��'��--�7-����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$��    �   ��--�   ����-   -$  �   �
�
�   �--�    ����-   -$
�
���
�--�    ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  -'��'��--�7-����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$��    �   ��--�   ����-   -$  �   �
�
�   �--�    ����-   -$
�
���
�--�    ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  ����-   -$�����--�  -'��'��-���� Arial-     ��� 2

1   2
+
2   2
<
3   2
M
4   2
^
5   2
o
6   2
�
7   2
�
8   2
�
9
2
�10
2
�11--   ������-7-@  !�--�7-����-
-$--�
����-
-$--�
����-
-$--�
����-
-$--�
����-
-$--�
����-
-$--�
����-
-$--�
����-
-$--�
����-
-$      --�
����-
-$  

        --�
����-
-$


--�
����-
-$--�
����-
--�
����-
--�
����-
-$--�
����-
-$--�
����-
-$--�
-'��'��--�7-����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$��    �   ��--�
����-
-$� �
�
�   �   --�
����-
-$�
���
�
--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
��--�
����-
--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
-'��'��--�7-����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$��    �   ��--�
����-
-$� �
�
�   �   --�
����-
-$�
���
�
--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
��--�
����-
--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
-'��'��--�7-����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$��    �   ��--�
����-
-$� �
�
�   �   --�
����-
-$�
���
�
--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
��--�
����-
--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
����-
-$�����--�
-'��'��--�7-����-
-$55665--�
����-
-$55665--�
����-
-$55665--�
����-
-$55665--�
����-
-$55665--�
����-
-$55665--�
����-
-$55665--�
����-
-$55665--�
����-
-$55    6   65--�
����-
-$5 5
6
6   5   --�
����-
-$5
566
5
--�
����-
-$55665--�
����-
65--�
����-
--�
����-
-$55665--�
����-
-$55665--�
����-
-$55665--�
-'��'��--       ��� 2
JA      2
�B      2
�C      2
D   -����-
    ������@ !�@ !�-&&iAFf



(

    ���62'��'��-    --'�����    ����7����-  ���@    !��]����� Calibri--
Alberta Weekly Fed Steer Prices

    

            

    



���� Calibri-2
.Source:  CanFax2
2   Cdn $/cwt���� Calibri-
2Week
22012
22013
_2014   2
pK1���� Calibri-2
p�114.992
p�117.452
p130.56-    2
�K2-2
��113.912
��116.502
�133.64-    2
�K3-2
��114.162
��115.262
�138.51-    2
�K4-2
��113.662
��115.102
�142.52-    2
�K5-2
��112.082
��116.242
�139.78-    2
�K6-2
��110.792
��116.332
�138.14����--'��--���   �7����-�    �����������-��-@    !��-��-@    !��-��-@    !��-]]�-@   !�h]-+�]�-@ !�2+�-+�]�-@    !�2+�-+�]�-@    !�2+�-6]6-@ !�L6-nn�-@  !�hn-�-@    !��-o���-@  !�go�-o���-@    !�go�-o���-@    !�go�-o6�6-@    !�go6-8-@   !�-**8-@    !�*-;;8-@   !�;-LL8-@   !�L-8-@ !�-��8-@    !��-��8-@   !��-��8-@   !��-��8-@   !��-��8-@   !��--'��-���    ����7�7-'��-��� ����7�- �����-7-@   !�7-�-@ !��-'��#A���7(��
���CCAAlberta Fed Steer PriceWorksheets 
 !"#$%&'()*����,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv����xyz{|}~����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������Root Entry���������F����Workbook�������������USummaryInformation(����+L�DocumentSummaryInformation8������������w
```

When I access the link : https://www.canfax.ca/Report/SpreadsheetReport.aspx?catalogue=FullSpreadsheets&group=Weekly+Fed+Steer&report=Alberta in the browser, an excel file gets downloaded:

[image]

For the spreadsheet link, These are the headers and payload values:

[image]

I tried a lot and I am new to scraping and python. Please help. Thank you

Comment: Excel files are not basic text you need to read the file correctly. Try `xlrd`

Comment: @ViaTech Could you give an example of how i could use it with the url?

Comment: @ViaTech I tried the xlrd method and i got an error: XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\r\n\r\n<!DO'

Answer (score 0):

This worked : excel_data = pd.read_excel(t.content). now read_excel reads binary data as well